# How to use definite integrals in solution of nth order linear ODE with variable coefficients?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider a first-order inhomogeneous linear system $$x'(t)=A(t)x(t)+b(t).$$ Here $A:I\to\mathbb R^{n\times n}$ and $b: I\to\mathbb R^n$, where $I\subset \mathbb R$. Through the method of variation of parameters, one can obtain the solution $$x(t)=F(t)\int (F(t))^{-1}b(t)dt,\tag1$$ where $F(t)$ is the fundamental matrix associated with the homogenous system, i.e. the columns are the solutions to the homogenous system. Since a scalar $n$-th order ODE can be reduced to a system, the corresponding solution to $$y^{(n)}(t)+a_{n-1}(t)y^{(n-1)}(t)+\ldots +a_0(t)y(t)=f(t)$$ is $$y(t)=R_1(t)\int K_n(t)f(t)dt,\tag2$$ where $R_1(t)$ is the first row of the fundamental matrix and $K_n(t)$ the last column of the inverse of the fundamental matrix.

---

Now, I know it's possible to rewrite $(1)$ in terms of definite integrals; the formula reads $$x(t)=F(t)(F(t_0))^{-1}x_0+F(t)\int_{t_0}^t (F(u))^{-1}b(u)du,\tag3$$ which is useful if you have an initial value $x_0=x(t_0)$ to the system, but is it also possible to rewrite $(2)$ in terms of a definite integral when given the initial values $(y(t_0),\ldots,y^{(n-1)}(t_0))$? I have taken a look at Teschl's book, but I struggle very much with the notation there, in particular theorem 3.13. Anyway, grateful for any help. (The formulas $(1)$ and $(2)$ are taken from [here](https://www.math.uni-bielefeld.de/%7Egrigor/odelec2009.pdf), page 66.)

Comment: Here's my educated guess. The solution to the scalar $n$th order linear ODE, with initial values $(y(t_0),\ldots,y^{(n-1)}(t_0))=x_0$ should just be the first component of $x(t)$, i.e. the first component of $F(t)(F(t_0))^{-1}x_0$ and the first component of $F(t)\int_{t_0}^t (F(u))^{-1}b(u)du$. Is this observation correct?